# deal with one user model for multiple type of user in django rest framework

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a multiple type user api with django rest framework in my project i have two types of users:
-customer who is an individual user
-corporates who are companies

What i'm trying to achieve is to have two separates users on the admin apnel whith its own viewset at the endpoint but for django corporates and individual user are users so when i display my individual user endpoint in json django render information for customer&corporates but the only one i want in the json is customer information not a both it's same issue for corporates endpoint

here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)


class PersonProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    nom = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
    dob = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    contact_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    contact_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)


class CorporateUserProfile(PersonProfile):
    # profile = models.ForeignKey(PersonProfile)
    representant_legal = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, 
               max_length=50)
    statut = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)



class IndividualUserProfile(PersonProfile):
    prenom = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)

    #class Meta:
    #    db_table = 'individual_user'
```

here is my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import User, PersonProfile, CorporateUserProfile, 
                 IndividualUserProfile

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        # model = PersonProfile
        model = CorporateUserProfile
        fields = ('nom', 'photo', 'dob', 'address', 'contact_1', 
                            'contact_2', 'country', 'city',
                  'representant_legal', 'statut')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'password', 'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        CorporateUserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile = instance.profile

        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.save()
        profile.nom = profile_data.get('nom', profile.nom)
        profile.photo = profile_data.get('photo', profile.photo)
        profile.dob = profile_data.get('dob', profile.dob)
        profile.address = profile_data.get('address', profile.address)
        profile.contact_1 = profile_data.get('contact_1', profile.contact_1)
        profile.contact_2 = profile_data.get('contact_2', profile.contact_2)
        profile.country = profile_data.get('country', profile.country)
        profile.city = profile_data.get('city', profile.city)
        profile.representant_legal = profile_data.get('representant_legal', profile.representant_legal)
        profile.statut = profile_data.get('statut', profile.statut)
        profile.save()

        return instance





class IndividualUserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        # model = PersonProfile
        model = IndividualUserProfile
        fields = ('nom', 'prenom', 'photo', 'dob', 'address', 'contact_1', 'contact_2', 'country', 'city')


class IndividualSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = IndividualUserProfileSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'password', 'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        IndividualUserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile = instance.profile

        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.save()
        profile.nom = profile_data.get('nom', profile.nom)
        profile.prenom = profile_data.get('nom', profile.prenom)
        profile.photo = profile_data.get('photo', profile.photo)
        profile.dob = profile_data.get('dob', profile.dob)
        profile.address = profile_data.get('address', profile.address)
        profile.contact_1 = profile_data.get('contact_1', profile.contact_1)
        profile.contact_2 = profile_data.get('contact_2', profile.contact_2)
        profile.country = profile_data.get('country', profile.country)
        profile.city = profile_data.get('city', profile.city)
        profile.save()

        return instance
```

here is my views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from api.models import User
from api.serializers import UserSerializer, IndividualSerializer
# Also add these imports
from api.permissions import IsLoggedInUserOrAdmin, IsAdminUser


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    # Add this code block
    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = []
        if self.action == 'create':
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve' or self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'partial_update':
            permission_classes = [IsLoggedInUserOrAdmin]
        elif self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]




class IndividualViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # queryset = User.objects.all()
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividualSerializer

    # Add this code block
    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = []
        if self.action == 'create':
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve' or self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'partial_update':
            permission_classes = [IsLoggedInUserOrAdmin]
        elif self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

this what I have at the endpoint of individual user is a list of individual users and companies in the same json  what went wrong?:

```
# Create your tests here.

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/",
        "email": "vend@gmail.com",
        "profile": null
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/",
        "email": "vendeur@gmail.com",
        "profile": {
            "nom": "noname",
            "prenom": null,
            "photo": null,
            "dob": null,
            "address": "BP 137 Yaounde rue1037",
            "contact_1": "+237 668982566",
            "contact_2": "+237 668982569",
            "country": "Cameroun",
            "city": "Yaounde"
        }
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/3/",
        "email": "georges@gmail.com",
        "profile": {
            "nom": "noname",
            "prenom": null,
            "photo": null,
            "dob": null,
            "address": "BP 137 Douala rue 1137",
            "contact_1": "+237 668982567",
            "contact_2": "+237 668982570",
            "country": "Cameroun",
            "city": "Douala"
        }
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/4/",
        "email": "jeiffey@gmail.com",
        "profile": {
            "nom": "noname",
            "prenom": null,
            "photo": null,
            "dob": null,
            "address": "BP 137 Bafoussam rue 1134",
            "contact_1": "+237 668982568",
            "contact_2": "+237 668982571",
            "country": "Cameroun",
            "city": "Bafoussam"
        }
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/5/",
        "email": "degrasguemto@gmail.com",
        "profile": {
            "nom": "noname",
            "prenom": null,
            "photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/uploads/963840d34c51efe6fbe57749fb434646.jpg",
            "dob": "2019-09-22T13:46:23.682584Z",
            "address": "BP 137 Yaounde rue 5024",
            "contact_1": "+237 691679613",
            "contact_2": "+237 678590793",
            "country": "Cameroun",
            "city": "Yaounde"
        }
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/6/",
        "email": "gdegras@gmail.com",
        "profile": {
            "nom": "degras",
            "prenom": null,
            "photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/uploads/Lamp-3D-Wallpaper-photos-images_VcIDh6z.jpg",
            "dob": "2019-09-22T22:23:08.271455Z",
            "address": "BP 3306 Yaounde rue 1137",
            "contact_1": "+237 691679613",
            "contact_2": "+237 678590793",
            "country": "Cameroun",
            "city": "Yaounde"
        }
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/7/",
        "email": "IUTFV@gmail.com",
        "profile": {
            "nom": "IUT FV",
            "prenom": null,
            "photo": null,
            "dob": "2019-09-22T22:25:22.702443Z",
            "address": "BP 137 Bafoussam rue 1134",
            "contact_1": "+237 668982566",
            "contact_2": "+237 668982569",
            "country": "Cameroun",
            "city": "Yaounde"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add your code so that we can get a better understanding of what you tried.

Comment: extend User model and add a feild "role" with values "user" and "corporate"

Comment: sandeep field "role" in the extend User model? more explanation please?

Comment: sandeep  thanks for your help i've finaly get what you mean by saying add field role